# Jumpheight and Gravity is based on framerate in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some very rudimentary movement code for a character controller in unity.

It appears as though my jumpheight gets higher with higher frames, whereas gravity gets lower with higher frames. I did try to do some stuff with Time.deltaTime, though that hasn't fixed anything.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour

{
    public float speed = 10f;
    private CharacterController characterController;
    private float sensitivity = 1.8f;
    private float xRotation = 0f;
    public Camera camera;
    private float jumpHeight = 550f;
    private float gravity = -170f;
    private float yvelocity = 0f;
    private bool land = false;
    public AudioSource landSound;
    void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
        camera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 10, 0);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)){
            speed = 15f;
        }
        else {
            speed = 10f;
        }
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);

        Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        Vector3 right = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right);
        Vector3 move = ((forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical")) * speed + (right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")) * speed);

        if (characterController.isGrounded){
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)){
                yvelocity = jumpHeight;
            }
            if (yvelocity <= 0 ){
                yvelocity = 0;
            }
        }        

        yvelocity += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        move = move + Vector3.up * yvelocity * Time.deltaTime;

        characterController.Move(move * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

It's not very well written but it gets the job done. (Clearly not anymore though)

Comment: I think it should only be `move += Vector3.up * yvelocity;` instead .. otherwise you double multiply by the `Time.deltaTime` ... your gravity also seems oddly high

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [`FixedUpdate()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html), instead of `Update()`. FixedUpdate is on a fixed interval (default is 0.02 seconds), which is used with Unity's physics system. You should use FixedUpdate with all physics/movement related things, so it is not associated with frame rate.

Make sure you also replace any instances of `Time.DeltaTime` with `Time.FixedDeltaTime` within that `FixedUpdate`, as `DeltaTime` is the time the last frame took, and `FixedDeltaTime` is that fixed interval.